# Constraint two coaxial rods for FEA using ABAQUS CAE, where the outer and inner can rotate vertically and also the inner one can move axially

Tags: abaqus, boundary, finite-element-analysis

I am trying to constraint two coaxial (X direction) rods for FEA using ABAQUS CAE.

Boundary Conditions are: the outer and the inner rod can rotate vertically (Y direction), but the inner can move axially without the outer moving. Can somebody give me some hints how to define it in the Abaqus modules?

p.s. The axis of the rods are on the X direction.

Thank you,

I've tried to apply a vertical rotation to the outer rod, and then constraint the inner and outer, so the inner follows the outer but it seems that only outer rod is rotating!